# Creating of a type guard when array is marked as const

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I am using as const in order to create union type of array like the example bellow.
I would like to have a type guard to check if a string is type of this union type.
I can hardcode another array in the type guard but I don't think this is a good
approach.  How I can solve this issue?

```
const items = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;

// here we have the union type - 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
type itemType = typeof items[number];

// Here I would like to create a typeguard like this: 
const isItemType = (item: string): item is itemType => {
  // here I am getting 
  // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of 
  // type '"a" | "b" | "c"'.(2345)
  return items.includes(item);
}
```

Comment: `items.includes(item as itemType)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe This works. However I would like to avoid casting if it is possible. In fact the idea of typeguards is to avoid as assertion. :)

Comment: It's an [_assertion_](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), not a cast, and isn't avoidable for the reason TSC is erroring. Note the documented examples of predicates also use assertions, for much the same reason: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates.

Comment: You can widen `items` to `readonly string[]` without an assertion and then do the `includes()` check.  But an assertion is fine if you know something the compiler doesn’t know.  See the answer to the question this duplicates.